# python classes adding numbers

Tags: python, class

I need to write a class, Numbers, with methods addNumbers and currentSum, that prints the current sum. Eg.:

```
numbers = Numbers()
numbers.addNumber(3)
numbers.addNumber(2)
print numbers.currentSum()
```

should print 5

I have made a class:

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self, numbers):
    self.numbers=addNumbers
    return numbers.currentSum()
Numbers=Numbers()
```

A hint, anyone?

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, use `class X(object):` instead. `class X:` is an old style class.. [Here are the differences](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Answer (score 4):

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
       self.__sum=0
    def addNumber(self, number):
       self.__sum += number
    def currentSum(self):
       return self.__sum
```

Comment: That's... not a hint. That's doing the entire thing for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. You need to implement the `currentSum()` method
2. You also need to implement the `addNumber()` method
3. `addNumber()` will need to keep track of numbers across method calls. [Use a list.](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html)

More reading on methods: [What is a "method" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786881/what-is-a-method-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Numbers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0

    def addNumber(self, n):
        self.sum += n

    def currentSum(self):
        return self.sum
```