# Explain Python code for listing all permutations

Tags: python, generator, permutation

```
class Permutation:
    def __init__(self,justalist):
        self._data = justalist[:]
        self._sofar = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.next()
    def next(self):
        for elem in self._data:
            if elem not in self._sofar:
                self._sofar.append(elem)
                if len(self._sofar) == len(self._data):
                    yield self._sofar[:]
                else:
                    for v in self.next():
                        yield v
                self._sofar.pop()
```

Found this code online ( http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/yield.html ). Tried to figure it out, but haven't made much headway. The part that is really tripping me up is the:

```
                 for v in self.next():
                    yield v
                 self._sofar.pop()
```

To code for the class is run by doing:

```
      for i in Permutation(a):
         print(i)
```

I've read this:

> "by invoking yield, the next member is now a generator function, so we can't just simply call next again - if we did, we would lose the returned generator object, and thus, the returned permutations! We must instead loop over the returned results with a simple for v in self.next(): yield v. This way, the results are properly propagated to the "parent" call."

I don't know if this explains what is going on, but it means nothing to me. (I thought I understood generators.)

Comment: try playing a bit with `yield`, write a generator function or two and you'll figure it out. one of the coolest bits about python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is that `Permutation.next()` yields all permutations of the items in `_data` that begin with `_sofar`.

To do this, we try adding on each possible element onto the end of `_sofar`. There are then two cases: either `_sofar` is long enough (i.e., we've got a complete permutation), in which case we just yield a copy of it; or it isn't (i.e., we've got a partial permutation), in which case we recursively call `next` -- which, in general, yields lots of permutations, so we have to yield them on ourselves one by one.

Incidentally, I think the code would be neater and easier to understand if it went more like this (DANGER: untested code):

```
def next(self):
    if len(self._sofar) == len(self._data):
        yield self._sofar[:]
    else:
        for elem in self._data:
            if elem not in self._sofar:
                self._sofar.append(elem)
                for v in self.next():
                    yield v
                self._sofar.pop()
```

which also has the merit of giving the right answer when there are no elements (there's exactly one permutation, the empty sequence; the code as given yields none). There are a few optimizations I'd be inclined to make, too, but they aren't important.

Comment: McGaughan ... still having trouble. Are you saying that self.next() is recursively next(self)?

Comment: supposed to be "recursively calling" next(self)

Comment: Yup, self.next() calls self.next() recursively. What makes the recursion bottom out eventually is that each call has one more element in `_sofar` than its parent, and when `_sofar` gets "full" we don't make the recursive call.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question. Sorry if my previous response missed the point. When you call a method on an object -- e.g., `self.next()` -- what happens behind the scenes is that the `next` function gets called with the object as its first argument. So `x.foo(1,2,3)` turns into `foo(x,1,2,3)`. So when you define a method, its first argument is always the object it's being applied to, and it's conventional to give that the name `self`.

Comment: (1) does self.next() call self(next) recursively. (2) how? given that one function has an argument and the other doesn't. Where is self.next() even defined? Furthermore, if I take a generator object (call it a), and I do a.next(), I get an error message. I have to call next(a). So how is self.next() even being run?

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation of this stuff in AndiDog's answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786881/what-is-a-method-in-python

Comment: (Sorry, that wasn't a response to your latest comment, which I hadn't seen when I posted it.) So, here's how it goes. (1) When you iterate over a `Permutation` object `p`, the magic of the iterator protocol means that `p.next()` gets called. That's the method whose definition begins `def next(self):`. (2) `p` gets passed to that as its first parameter; so inside that method, `self` is the object `p`. (3) Within that code there's a call to `self.next()`, which is calling the exact same method again, on the same object.

Comment: It's worth noting that, as ninjagecko points out, this class is *not* a good example of how the iterator protocol is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3):

This class is a generator that recursively calls itself (`self.next()`).

It is a bit odd, because when you ask the generator for all its values, it doesn't really follow the iteration protocol by returning `self` (an object with a `.next()` function) like you'd expect. Rather, it returns the result of `self.next()`, which is quite poor wording. The `next` function should rather just be called `permutations()`, because the `next` function really has nothing whatsoever to do with the fact that a `next` function is required in the iteration protocol.

Anyway, you can see the recursive trace of this if you augment the function with a recursion depth parameter:

```
class Permutation:
    def __init__(self,justalist):
        self._data = justalist[:]
        self._sofar = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.next()
    def next(self, depth=0):
        debug = lambda text:print('\t'*depth+' '+text)
        for elem in self._data:
            #print( 'self._data: {}'.format(self._data) )
            #print( 'self._sofar: {}'.format(self._sofar) )
            if elem not in self._sofar:
                self._sofar.append(elem)
                if len(self._sofar) == len(self._data):
                    debug( 'yielding self._sofar[:]: {}'.format(self._sofar[:]) )
                    yield self._sofar[:]
                else:
                    for v in self.next(depth+1):
                        debug( 'yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: {}'.format(v) )
                        yield v
                self._sofar.pop()
```

Demo:

```
>>> list( Permutation(range(4)) )
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 2, 3]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 2, 3]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 1, 3, 2]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 3, 2]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 3, 2]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 1, 3, 2]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 2, 1, 3]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 1, 3]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 1, 3]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 1, 3]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 2, 3, 1]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 3, 1]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 3, 1]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 2, 3, 1]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 3, 1, 2]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 1, 2]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 1, 2]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 1, 2]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [0, 3, 2, 1]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 2, 1]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 2, 1]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [0, 3, 2, 1]
                         yielding self._sofar[:]: [1, 0, 2, 3]
                 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [1, 0, 2, 3]
         yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [1, 0, 2, 3]
 yielding elements of self.next() one-by-one: [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

As you can see, the flow of the data is as follows: recursion proceeds to the deepest level (4 in this case, `len([0,1,2,3])` is 4), produces a permutation, and yields it back up to the previous level. That level yields it back up to the previous level, etc. At the highest level, the yield returns it.

**In conclusion, this is a broken and terrible implementation**, since:

1. It could just be accomplished by a recursive functional pattern with this extra Class nonsense
2. It defines `next()` in a way that strongly implies something, but actually does something else.
3. It will fail if any values are duplicated, e.g. `Permutation([0,1,1])` will fail

You should just use http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations (`from itertools import permutations`)