# Easy Logical Error In Python - My Function Calling Isn't Working Properly

Tags: python, function, oop, csv, functional-programming

I can't get my "doLogicForColumn5" function to affect my program. Column 5 of the CSV output should be filled with various values, but instead it's all the same number (12.12).

Lines 14-27 to be specific--they're simply not working!

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import string # for capwords
date = "7/5/2015"
monthlybudget = 100000
dailybudget = monthlybudget/30
#campaign variables
levels = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"]]
language = [["english"], ["spanish"]]
variables = [["1"], ["2"]]
nouns = [["wordA1"], ["+wordA2"]]
adjectives1 = [["wordB1"], ["wordB2"]]
adjectives2 = [["wordC1"], ["wordC2"]]
def doLogicForColumn5(self): # budget
    self.column5 = dailybudget/36 
    if self.language == ["spanish"]: 
        self.column5 = self.column5 * .6
        if self.level == ["1"]:
            self.column5 = self.column5*.8
        else:
            self.column5 = self.column5*.1
    else: #if spanish
        self.column5 = self.column5*.4
        if self.level == ["1"]:
            self.column5 = self.column5*.2
        else:
            self.column5 = self.column5*.3
class Row(object):
    column1 = "column1"
    column2 = "column2"
    column3 = "column3"
    column4 = "column4"
    column5 = "budget"
    def __init__(self, level, language, noun, adjective1, adjective2, variable):
        self.level = level
        self.level = str(self.level)
        self.language = language
        self.language = str(self.language)
        self.noun = noun
        self.noun = str(self.noun)
        self.adjective1 = adjective1
        self.adjective1 = str(self.adjective1)
        self.adjective2 = adjective2
        self.adjective2 = str(self.adjective2)
        self.variable = variable
        self.variable = str(self.variable)
    def rowEntry(self, level, language, noun, adjective1, adjective2, variable):
        doLogicForColumn5(self)
        lol = [[self.column1], [self.column2], [self.column3], [self.column4], [self.column5]]
        lol[0] = self.column1
        lol[1] = self.column2
        lol[2] = self.column3
        lol[3] = self.column4
        lol[4] = self.column5
        file_writer.writerow([o for o in lol])
with open("test.csv", "wb") as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for a in range(0, len(levels)):
        for e in range(0, len(language)):    
            for y in range (0, len(nouns)):
                for x in range (0, len(adjectives1)):
                    for w in range (0, len(adjectives2)):
                        for n in range(0, len(variables)):
                            city = "n/a"
                            stateVersion = "n/a"
                            food = Row(levels[a], language[e], nouns[y], adjectives1[x], adjectives2[w], variables[n])                    
                            food.rowEntry(levels[a], language[e], nouns[y], adjectives1[x], adjectives2[w], variables[n])
```

Comment: Please use `itertools.product` so I don't have to see you nest your `for` loops any deeper

Comment: Also `def doLogicForColumn5(self)` doesn't exist within the context of your `class`.... so it is just a free function that happens to have an argument that you named `self`

Comment: Ohh, so I should put the function inside the class? And sorry, what do you mean about the itertools.product? I'm not familiar with it

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981789/difference-between-methods-and-functions) you must define it as a *method* so it is bound to a variable, and therefore has an instance of the variable to access.

Comment: And for the other comment, you can delete your 6 `for` loops and replace it with just 1 loop `for a, e, y, x, w, n in itertools.product(levels, language, nouns, adjectives1, adjectives2, variables)`

Comment: Thanks. So instead of calling it like doLogicForColumn5 I will instead do A = doLogicForColumn5 to instantiate the method class?

Comment: No, I mean take the entire function definition, and move it within `class Row`, like `__init__` and `rowEntry` are.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same number for every value in column5. Now it's a different number than before, though! it's 11.04. Thank you SO much for your help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
for a in range(0, len(levels)):
```

so `a` is a number. Then:

```
food = Row(levels[a],
```

and so `levels[a]` is a `list` such as `["1"]`. Then, when you `__init__()` a `Row`:

```
self.level = level
self.level = str(self.level)
```

So now `self.level` is a string. Then, in `doLogicForColumn5()`:

```
if self.level == ["1"]
```

Recall that `self.level` was cast as a string earlier. So `self.level` will never be equal to a `list` of `["1"]`. It may, however, be equal to a string of `"['1']"`, so it would make more sense to compare to that. Better yet, turn the global `levels` into a flat `list` like `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]`. The best option would be for `levels` to simply be `'123456'` and refactor your program to use that simpler structure.

Same goes for `self.language` and any other variables which have been set to a single-element `list` within a larger `list`.

Check your code for other instances of unnecessary complexity, as that sort of thing will eventually bite you (as another example, the `doLogicForColumn5()` function should really just be a method in `Row`, as commenters are suggesting).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I'm having trouble with your point about turning variables into Strings. Even if I change if self.level == ["1"] to if self.level == '["1"]' I end up with every row having the same value. As for having levels as a "flat list", isn't it already?

Comment: No, it is currently a `list` where each element is itself a `list`. Each of these nested `list`s contains a string. Since all you want to do is iterate over `'1'`, `'2'`, etc., you can just set it to a string `'123456'` and refactor your program to use that simpler structure.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but I'm really looking for the path of least resistance get my "doLogicForColumn5" function to affect my coumn5 properly. Is there any advice you can give me about that?

Comment: The thing is, `'["1"]' != "['1']"`. When Python casts objects to `str`, it tries to make the representation stick with single quotes `'` when it can. That means that you need to tell the program to expect something with the appropriate quotes, as I specified in this answer.