# Database abstraction with Julia

Tags: database, orm, julia

Many languages provide database abstraction to save data (objects) to relational databases (generally through object relational mapping (ORM)).

I'm aware that Julia is not a "conventional" object oriented language (see [julia: OOP or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755737/julia-oop-or-not) )

But I wonder if a library with the following features exists ?

- Connect to a database through a database URI like `"dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database"` (see Python SQLAlchemy http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html )
- Store objects (in fact instances of composite type) to a DB
- Retrieve objects from DB

Comment: There is a Google Summer of Code project (I think the accepted projects will be announced today, April 22, 2016) that will provide just such an API.

Comment: I have been looking at https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6453977159827456/ but I wasn't able to find anything related to Julia and database ;-(

Comment: Unfortunately, her proposal wasn't accepted

Answer (score 2):

The JuliaDB collection lists various ways (i.e. julia libraries) to connect to databases, most of which should support the above functionality.

See https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaDB.jl