# Is there a straightforward way to use SQLAlchemy in Julia?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, julia

In connection with the question on [ORM for Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750645/database-abstraction-with-julia) I am wondering how to get about using SQLAlchemy in Julia given that SQLAlchemy uses a lot of object/type magic to load and persist data. Do you have any hints how to use Julia structures in the context of SQLAlchemy?

(I am sorry, I am new to Julia, just looking around at this point and I am currently unable to come up with some code for a start - as MCVE).

Comment: SQLAlchemy is a Python library. Does Julia allow running Python code?

Comment: Yes, very conveniently, see PyCall.jl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) lets you load and use arbitrary python packages, including SQLAlchemy.

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> @pyimport sqlalchemy as sql

julia> sql.__version__
"1.1.9"
```

Please see it's documentation for further details.

As of now there are some arguably inconvenient syntax mappings necessary. Concretely, you must access python object fields and methods by `object[:field]` instead of `object.field` which you'd use in python. Nevertheless, since my [pull request](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/pull/517) has been merged this week this is going to change once [PyCall 2.0](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/629) is out! (Of course you can checkout the master branch through `] add PyCall#master` and get this feature already now.)