# What is a string method, and how are does their usage differ from using a built-in function?

Tags: python

What is a string method, and how are does their usage differ from using a built-in function?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "string method"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981789/difference-between-methods-and-functions)

Comment: str.center(width[, fillchar]) 

I don't know how to answer to this question