# Python method vs function

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I am seeking for a confirmation if my thinking is correct in terms of Python method vs function:

A method is a part of a class.

A function is defined outside of a class.

so e.g.

```
class FooBar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
        pass


def bar():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fb = FooBar()
```

I understand `def foo` defines method and `def bar` defines function. Am I correct?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: Yes, you have the correct basic idea.

Comment: Please research before asking, your title alone should have easily found you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981789/difference-between-methods-and-functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. To be clear, methods *are functions*, they are simply attached to the class, and when that function is called from an instance it gets  that instance passed implicitly as the first argument automagically*. It doesn't actually matter where that function is defined. Consider:

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def foo(self):
        return '|'.join(self.n*['foo'])


fb = FooBar(2)

print(fb.foo())

def bar(self):
    return '*'.join(self.n*['bar'])

print(bar(fb))

FooBar.bar = bar

print(fb.bar())
```

---

*I highly recommend reading the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Spoiler alert, [Functions are descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). This is how Python magically passes instances to methods (that is, *all function objects are descriptors who's `__get__` method passes the instance as the first argument to the function itself when accessed by an instance on a class!*. The HOWTO shows Python implementations of all of these things, including how you could implement `property` in pure Python!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, methods and functions in Python are exactly the same thing!

It matters not one bit where it is defined. What matters is how it is looked up.

```
def defined_outside(*args):
    return args

class C:

    def defined_inside(*args):
        return args

C.defined_outside = defined_outside
defined_inside = C.defined_inside

instance = C()

print(         defined_inside (1,2))
print(         defined_outside(1,2))
print(instance.defined_inside (1,2))
print(instance.defined_outside(1,2))
```

which gives the output

```
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(<__main__.C object at 0x7f0c80d417f0>, 1, 2)
(<__main__.C object at 0x7f0c80d417f0>, 1, 2)
```

(This will only work in Python 3: Two of these will produce a `TypeError` in Python 2.)

What is important to notice about the output is that, in the first two cases, the functions receive two arguments: `1` and `2`. In the last two cases they receive three arguments: `instance`, `1` and `2`.

In the cases where `instance` is passed to the function, the function is behaving like a method. In the cases where `instance` is *not* passed in, the function is behaving like a plain function. But notice that both behaviours are exhibited by both the function which was *defined* inside the classe and the one which was *defined* outside the class.

What matters is how the function was looked up. If it was looked up as an attribute of an *instance* of a class, then the function behaves like a method; otherwise it behaves like a free function.

[Incidentally, this *binding behaviour* only works for pure Python functions; it does not work for functions defined using the Python/C API. The latter always behave like functions and never like methods:

```
C.dir = dir
instance.dir()
```

will give you a directory of the global scope, not of `instance`, indicating that `dir` recived zero arguments, rather that receiving `instance` as an argument.
]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. There is a lot out there about written on how python methods are different from python functions.