# Why does `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` behave differently with lambdas than named functions

Tags: python, cython, cpython

I was recently experimenting with monkey patching built in types (Yes I know this is a terrible idea---trust me, this is for educational purposes only).

I discovered that there is an odd distinction between `lambda` expressions and functions declared with `def`. Take a look at this `iPython` session:

```
In [1]: %load_ext cython

In [2]: %%cython
   ...: from cpython.object cimport PyObject_GenericSetAttr
   ...: def feet_to_meters(feet):
   ...: 
   ...:     """Converts feet to meters"""
   ...: 
   ...:     return feet / 3.28084
   ...: 
   ...: PyObject_GenericSetAttr(int, 'feet_to_meters', feet_to_meters)

In [3]: (20).feet_to_meters()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-63ba776af1c9> in <module>()
----> 1 (20).feet_to_meters()

TypeError: feet_to_meters() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Now, if I wrap `feet_to_meters` with a `lambda`, everything works!

```
In [4]: %%cython
   ...: from cpython.object cimport PyObject_GenericSetAttr
   ...: def feet_to_meters(feet):
   ...: 
   ...:     """Converts feet to meters"""
   ...: 
   ...:     return feet / 3.28084
   ...: 
   ...: PyObject_GenericSetAttr(int, 'feet_to_meters', lambda x: feet_to_meters(x))

In [5]: (20).feet_to_meters()
Out[5]: 6.095999804928006
```

What is going on with this?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but trying to set `int.feet_to_meters` in Python doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, the only way to modify builtin types is via the C-API

Comment: What you're seeing is a Cython thing, not a regular Python thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced in Python and without (very) dirty tricks:

```
class A:
   pass

A.works = lambda x: abs(1)
A.dont = abs

A().works()  # works
A().dont()   # error
```

The difference is, that `abs` is a builtin-function of type [`PyCFunctionObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/methodobject.h#L10), while lambda is of type [`PyFunctionObject`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/function.html?highlight=pyfunctionobject) (a C is missing compared to `PyCFunction...`).

Those cfunctions just cannot be used for patching, see for example [PEP-579](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0579/#cfunctions-do-not-become-methods).

The problem, which is also mentioned in PEP-579, that cython-functions are Py**C**Functions and thus are seen as builtin-functions:

```
%%cython
def foo():
    pass

>>> type(foo)
builtin_function_or_method
```

That means, you cannot use the Cython-function directly for monkey patching, but have to wrap them into a lambda or similar, as you already do. One should not worry about performance, because due to method-lookup there is already overhead, having a little bit more of it doesn't change things dramatically.

---

I must confess, I don't know why this is the case (historically). But in the current code (Python3.8) you can easily find the [crucial line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caba55b3b735405b280273f7d99866a046c18281/Objects/object.c#L1108) in [`_PyObject_GetMethod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caba55b3b735405b280273f7d99866a046c18281/Objects/object.c#L1085), which makes the difference:

```
descr = _PyType_Lookup(tp, name);
    if (descr != NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(descr);
        if (PyFunction_Check(descr) ||  # HERE WE GO
                (Py_TYPE(descr) == &PyMethodDescr_Type)) {
            meth_found = 1;
} else {
```

After looking-up the function (here `descr`) in the dictionary `_PyType_Lookup(tp, name)`, `method_found` is set to 1 only if the found function is of type `PyFunction`, which is not the case for builtin-Py**C**Functions. Thus `abs` and Co aren't seen as methods, but stay kind of "staticmethod".

The easiest way to find a starting point for the investigation, is to inspect the produced opcode for:

```
import dis
def f():
  a.fun()

dis.dis(f)
```

i.e. the following opcode(and seems to have changed since Python3.6):

```
2         0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
          2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (fun)  #HERE WE GO
          4 CALL_METHOD              0
          6 POP_TOP
          8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         10 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can inspect the corresponding part in [ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caba55b3b735405b280273f7d99866a046c18281/Python/ceval.c#L3110):

```
TARGET(LOAD_METHOD) {
            /* Designed to work in tamdem with CALL_METHOD. */
            PyObject *name = GETITEM(names, oparg);
            PyObject *obj = TOP();
            PyObject *meth = NULL;

            int meth_found = _PyObject_GetMethod(obj, name, &meth);
            ....
```

and let the [gdb take us from there](https://devguide.python.org/gdb/).

---

As @user2357112  has rightly pointed out, if Py**C**FunctionObject would support the descriptor protocol (more precisely to provide `tp_descr_get`), even after `meth_found = 0;` it still would have a fall back which would lead to the desired behavior. PyFunctionObject [does provide it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/funcobject.c#L633), but Py**C**FunctionObject [does not](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/methodobject.c#L271).

Older versions used `LOAD_ATTR`+`CALL_FUNCTION` for `a.fun()` and in order to work, function-objects had to support the descriptor protocol.  But now it seems not to be mandatory.

My quick tests with extending the crucial line with `PyCFunction_Check(descr)` to:

```
 if (PyFunction_Check(descr) || PyCFunction_Check(descr) ||
                (Py_TYPE(descr) == &PyMethodDescr_Type))
```

have shown, that then also builtin-methods would work as bound-methods (at least for the case above). But this would probably break something - I didn't run any bigger tests.

However, as @user2357112 mentioned (thanks again), this would lead to a inconsistency, because `meth = foo.bar` still uses `LOAD_ATTR` and thus depends on the descriptor protocol.

---

Recommendation: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982725/5769463) helpful in understanding, what is going on in the case of `LOAD_ATTR`.

Comment: The line you describe as the "crucial line" isn't really the crucial part. The crucial part is that C functions don't support the descriptor protocol. The code you're looking at is a fast-path to skip bound method object creation for a few common descriptor types; it's only an optimization, and even if functions written in Python didn't take that path, you'd see the same behavior due to the regular descriptor handling.

Comment: @user2357112 actually I'm asking myself, what prevents me to accept also `PyCFunctionObject` here in the same way I accept `PyFunctionObject`? The descriptors are no longer created/used when LOAD_METHOD` + `CALL_METHOD` are used...

Comment: Accepting PyCFunctionObject would be wrong because PyCFunctionObject does not support the descriptor protocol, and the LOAD_METHOD/CALL_METHOD fast path is supposed to produce the same behavior as the regular path. Otherwise, there would be a behavior difference between `foo.bar()` and `meth = foo.bar; meth()`.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you @ ead and @user2357112