# Why do you not have to return objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to Python and programming in general and I have just gotten into OOP. In Python, whatever is defined in a function's namespace is only valid while inside that namespace; once outside that space things like variables are forgotten:

```
def foo():
    a = 3

print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

As far as I know, besides returning data from functions, any information inside the function is lost at the end of the function call, and therein lies my question. Take the following code:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        self.name = 'John'

bar = Example('Jake')
bar.foo()
print(bar.name)

'John'
```

My question is: why don't you have to return objects after methods? In normal functions any variables are forgotten, but *in methods it seems data is actually appended to the object itself*, such as the `foo()` method being able to reference `self.name` despite `self.name` first being referenced in another method. Is this correct? Or is there a better technical explanation?

Comment: It’s called ‘scope’

Comment: This is a really good question! My guess would be that, you are calling the methods of an object, and not changing the object directly. What you are changing is the internal data items of the object. Another question would be, then how do the internal data items get updated then? That is a mystery to me, but I guess that all would be answered if we take a look at Python's internal mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this you will need to understand how self works. You can learn more here:
[Understanding self in python](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0)

In a nutshell, self refers to the calling object. Invoking `self.variable` refers to the variable associated with the calling object. Python is smart enough to create one if it doesn't exist.

*Calling `self.variable` inside a class is the same as calling `object.variable` with your object reference*

Consider the following example to prove this:

```
class Example:
    def print_x(self):
        print(self.x)

obj = Example()
obj.x = 5;    # Create a new attribute of the object and assign it a value 5
print(obj.x)  # Outputs 5
obj.print_x() # Outputs 5
```

In your example, I've added a couple of print statements to help you understand the state of the program during the execution:

```
    class Example:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(dir(self)) # Printing object contents before initializing name
        self.name = name # New attribute 'name' created
        print(dir(self)) # Printing object contents after initializing name

    def foo(self):
        print("Before foo, self.name = "+ self.name)
        self.name = 'John'
        print("After foo, self.name = "+ self.name)


bar = Example('Jake')
bar.foo()
print(bar.name)
```

The output of the above code is

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo']
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo', 'name']
Before foo, self.name = Jake
After foo, self.name = John
John
```

I will walk you through this code. When we first create bar, the `__init__()` method is called. Here we print the contents of the object using `dir(self)`. The output `['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo']` indicates that the object has only one member, the 'foo' method.

Now we create a new attribute called 'name' and assign it the value 'Jake'. Thus the object now has another member, the 'name' attribute as seen by the output of the next dir(self) `['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo', 'name']`

Now we call the foo method and print the value before and after the method. Before the `name` is changed in foo, the value of `name` associated with the object is "Jake". However, after the `name` is changed, the value of `self.name` is "John". This is indicated by

```
Before foo, self.name = Jake
After foo, self.name = John`
```

We next verify that the change made by changing `self.name` has indeed changed the value of `name` in `bar` by printing `bar.name` which gives us the expected output, `John`

Now coming back to your question, `self.name` is not an ordinary variable inside some method that is lost when we are out of scope. `self` can be used essentially anywhere inside the class to refer to the calling object (bar in this case). It is used to manipulate this calling object. Now since `bar` is within the scope, we are able to print its `name` attribute.

> In normal functions any variables are forgotten but in methods it
>   seems data is actually appended to the object itself

`self` manipulates the attributes in the object and is not limited to the scope of the method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I look forward to reading through the article about understanding self. Your point of self.variable being the same as object.variable also clicked in my head, as did the extremely detailed code breakdown. I was not familiar with the using the dir() function with objects, but I will be using it frequently now. Also your point of:

self.name is not an ordinary variable, self.name can be used essentially anywhere inside the class to refer to the **calling** object. That sentence was extremely helpful in understanding this, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

First, you don't have to return a value in a method, not in python, and not in many other programming languages. for example:

```
def append_a(lst):
    lst.append('a')

bob = []
append_a(bob)
print(bob)
['a']
```

Above we do not return anything in the function, but we use it to modify an existing data structure, this is very common almost anywhere.

Secondly, in your second example, you created an instance of the class Example, when you look at `self.something` you are looking at a member of the class, unlike other languages, where often members are only declared once, in python you can dynamically add members. 
Thus when looking at `bar.name` you are looking at a member of the class, its value on the instance `bar`. If you would look at a different instance, the value will be different.

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        self.name = 'John'

bar = Example('Jake')
bob = Example('Bob')
bar.foo()
print(bar.name)
print(bob.name)

John
Bob
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I forgot about functions being able to do things outside of their namespace, like appending lists. Also that is a good point about instances being unique and 'self' referencing the instance of the class, it helped clear things up in my head.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a lot of difference between methods and functions (See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981876/3829158) for details)

Though one important distinction, that you might have immediately noticed, is that methods have *self* as their first argument and we say that method *foo* is "bound" to instance *bar* of class *Example*, meaning simply that *foo* will be called with its first argument (*self*) as the instance  (*bar*) itself

With this knowledge lets see what the following function does:

```
class Example:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def foo(self):
    self.name = 'John'

bar = Example('Jake')
```

In method *init*, you assign *name* to *self*. But what is *self*? It is *bar* itself, so calling *init* can be thought of as doing

```
bar.name = 'Jake'
```

Then when you called method *foo*

```
bar.foo()
```

You equivalently did

```
bar.name = 'John'
```

So, it should not be surprising when finally the output of the following was 'John'

```
print(bar.name)  # John
```

About your query regarding methods not having to return anything, it is not quite so. Methods and functions may or may not return anything as (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465382/3829158)). But in this context, what is happening is an object passed to a method is being manipulated (self, which is bar, is being assigned a *name*) and because the object is alive after the method call completes, we can observe the changes done by the method (ie, we can see that bar.name is changed to 'John')

This works works with functions as well:

```
def another_foo(self):
  self.name = 'Mark'
baz = Example('Jake')
another_foo(baz)
print(baz.name)  # Mark
```

You see, this function did not return anything either. It worked just like the method *foo* by manipulating its argument. In fact, you could add it to the *Example* class and use it like a method

```
Example.another_foo = another_foo
new_bar = Example('Jake')
print(new_bar.name)  # Jake
new_bar.another_foo()
print(new_bar.name)  # Mark
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are thinking in the right direction. I'll start at a more basic level so that other beginner viewers can understand what is going on.

Think of `Example` as a template for creating new objects of a certain kind -- meaning the objects will all have the same attributes (also known as properties) and functionalities. For example, by drawing an analogy with real-life objects, all cars have the attribute "speed" and the functionality "accelerate".

The attribute *values* will be specific to the objects. For example, one car will have 0 mph speed and another 70 mph.

The attribute values at any point describe the **state** of an object. Methods, which you can think of as the object's functionalities, allow the ability to change an object's state.

`bar` is an object that you created using the template (that is, `class`) `Example`. If you have to describe this object's state, you'd tell us the values of its attributes. In this case, the object has only one attribute: `name`.

Now, this is the important part: `name` is not just any variable, it's an attribute of any object you make from the class `Example`. Think of `name` as always attached to the object. That's why you wrote `self.name = 'John'` and not `name = 'John'`. In the latter case, `name` would not be a part of the object `bar`, and no other method in the class would have access to the `name` variable.

So, to summarize, when you have created an object out of a class, think of the object as having various attributes. All the methods, or functionalities, of the object will have access to all those attributes. The values of the attributes would describe, at any point, the object's state at that moment. It is through that object's methods that one would change its state.

Finally, here's a great tool to visualize what happens at each line of your code: [pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20Example%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20name%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.name%20%3D%20name%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20foo%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.name%20%3D%20'John'%0A%0Abar%20%3D%20Example%28'Jake'%29%0Abar.foo%28%29%0Aprint%28bar.name%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was extremely helpful. Your point of objects having a 'state' and methods being able to change this state (aka values) really clicked in my head. Also the distinction between self.name = 'John" and name = 'John' was also helpful in understanding the difference and use of self. Again thank you very much for your reply, I will definitely reference it again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what is called as 'scoping' in OOP. And though the difference between classes and functions might seem subtle, it makes a big difference.

Simply said, functions rely on global and local variables. Global variables are objects that you define in the global workspace. This is like having a workbench and getting to use a common object across your functions and classes that you define. And so, for example, if you modify your function `foo()` to include an argument, like so:

```
a = 3 # This is globally defined

def foo(a):
  a = 3 * a
  return a

print(foo(a))
9
```

Changing the global value of `a` to something like `2` will give you 6 as the answer. We 'return' an object because it is locally defined within the scope of a function. In this example above, `foo()` performs the local operation `3 * a` and defines it locally to `a` itself and returns it. And so you can also *skip* the global variable `a` when executing `foo()` and define it locally within the function scope:

```
print(foo(6)) # Locally defined
18

print(a)
3 # Returns global variable
```

Classes on the other hand need to be *declared* and that has been very nicely explained by members (see above).