# PyFITS: hdulist.writeto()

Tags: python, arrays, astronomy, fits, pyfits

I'm extracting extensions from a multi-extension FITS file, manipulate the data, and save the data (with the extension's header information) to a new FITS file.

To my knowledge pyfits.writeto() does the task.  However, when I give it a data parameter in the form of an array, it gives me the error:

```
    'AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower''
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    'file = 'hst_11166_54_wfc3_ir_f110w_drz.fits'
     hdulist = pyfits.open(dir + file)'
     sci = hdulist[1].data # science image data
     exp = hdulist[5].data # exposure time data
     sci = sci*exp # converts electrons/second to electrons
     file = 'test_counts.fits'

     hdulist.writeto(file,sci,clobber=True)

     hdulist.close()
```

I appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you can, avoid the use of the variable name `file` since it means sth in Python. Also, you have an extra `'` before `file`, is it a mistake you did while copying the code? Besides, can we see the whole code? The error is talking about the `lower` method, but I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the [`HDUList.writeto`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/api/hdulists.html#astropy.io.fits.HDUList.writeto) *method*, and the [`writeto`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/api/files.html#writeto) *function*.

What you're calling is a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786881/what-is-a-method-in-python) on the [`HDUList`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/api/hdulists.html#hdulist) object that is returned when you call [`pyfits.open`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/api/files.html#open).  You can think of this object as something like a file handle to your original drizzled FITS file.  You can manipulate this object in place and either write it out to a new file or save updates in place (if you open the file in `mode='update'`).

The `writeto` *function* on the other hand is not tied to any existing file.  It's just a high-level function for writing an array out to a file.  In your example you could write your array of electron counts out like:

```
pyfits.writeto(filename, data)
```

This will create a single-HDU FITS file with the array data in the PRIMARY HDU.

Do be aware of the admonishment at the top of this section of the docs: http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/index.html#convenience-functions

The functions like `pyfits.writeto` are there for convenience in interactive work, but are not recommendable for use in code that will be run repeatedly, as in a script.  Instead have a look at [these instructions](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.3/io/fits/index.html#creating-a-new-fits-file) to start.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because you should use `hdulist.writeto(file, clobber=True)`. There is only one required argument:
https://pythonhosted.org/pyfits/api_docs/api_hdulists.html#pyfits.HDUList.writeto
If you give a second argument, it is used for `output_verify` which should be a string, not a numpy array. This probably explains your `AttributeError ...`.

Comment: Although you're correct that they're not passing correct arguments to the writeto method, it's more that they're confusing two different interfaces in the API.  See my answer.